# Showing dynamic data(Progress) on my webpage

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, ajax, vb.net

I am developing a webpage which shows content of datatable in gridview. And also, there is a button named "Send To Excel". If user click this button, this program starts generating the report( write the datatable content into the excel file). After finish, a hyperlink appears and user can download the Excel file.

Some of the report is big. So it needs time to complete the generating of the Excel File.

I want to show some information during it generating the excel report file. Like,

10 records generated.
20 records generated.
30 records generated.
..
finished.

Above sentences are apeared in the same line. In other words, sentence is replaced by the next sentence. The inserting the data line is done in the For loop. So we can analyse the progress using this for loop. I am using ***VB.NET, ajax, jquery, css*** to develop it.

Any Ideas? Please give me some ideas. Help.

Appreciated.

Comment: Though I have never used this before, one way is to use [SignalR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852586.aspx). However, the more tedious, hard-to-maintain method is using a combination of JS, AJAX, PocessDelegate, WebMethod, Session, complete with abort process support. And I have used this approach before and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick and easy way of doing this is to incorporate the Ajax.NET UpdateProgress control.  It will display a "thinking" GIF while you are generating the report.

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdateProgressOverview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You've encountered a classic problem in web development. You can't update the UI while the server is processing a request. Or, rather, you can't have back and forth communication between the client and server over the course of a single request.

You could have the request spawn a new thread to actually do the processing, so the request returns immediately. Have the processing thread update a database with a progress status, and have the client continuously poll the db using ajax to get the progress.